# How to correctly use pandas diff while respecting time based index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Consider the following dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=["foo"])
df1.index = pd.to_timedelta( df1.index, unit="s")
df2 = df1.resample("0.3S").interpolate("linear")

df1.diff() # => column "foo" is 1
df2.diff() # => column "foo" is 0.3 (correctly)
```

Ideally, I'd be able to do something akin to `df2.diff(pd.to_timedelta("0.3", unit="s")`, however, that's not exactly right (and it doesn't work).

The real idea is that my `diff` function actually be time aware and represent a true `d/dt` of a time series.

i.e.

```
df2.diff() / df2.interval_duration # => columns "foo" is 1
```

The hack I'm using to achieve this right now is as follows:

```
dt = np.diff(df2.index / pd.to_timedelta(1,"s"))# <- because I can't do df2.index.diff()
df2["foo"].diff() / dt # <= correct result
```

The above is a bit clunky but it works. In particular, it yields a correct answer for arbitrarily sampled time series.

Any help is appreciated untangling this into an appropriate single statement.

---

**edit**:

so far the hack above has been distilled to:

```
df2["foo"] / df2.index.total_seconds()
```

bypassing the `diff()` method altogether and instead essentially implementing a `d/dt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be improved by division:

```
a = df2["foo"]/(df2.index/pd.to_timedelta(1,"s"))
```

Because it should be same like:

```
a = df2["foo"].diff()/(df2.index.to_series().diff()/pd.to_timedelta(1,"s"))
```

---

```
print (a)
00:00:00           NaN
00:00:00.300000    1.0
00:00:00.600000    1.0
00:00:00.900000    1.0
00:00:01.200000    1.0
00:00:01.500000    1.0
00:00:01.800000    1.0
00:00:02.100000    1.0
00:00:02.400000    1.0
00:00:02.700000    1.0
00:00:03           1.0
00:00:03.300000    1.0
00:00:03.600000    1.0
00:00:03.900000    1.0
00:00:04.200000    1.0
00:00:04.500000    1.0
00:00:04.800000    1.0
00:00:05.100000    1.0
00:00:05.400000    1.0
00:00:05.700000    1.0
00:00:06           1.0
00:00:06.300000    1.0
00:00:06.600000    1.0
00:00:06.900000    1.0
00:00:07.200000    1.0
00:00:07.500000    1.0
00:00:07.800000    1.0
00:00:08.100000    1.0
00:00:08.400000    1.0
00:00:08.700000    1.0
00:00:09           1.0
Freq: 300L, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ahh, that's actually a good idea. To bypass the `diff` method altogether.

I'll wait for a day or so to see if anyone comes up with any alternatives and then accept this as the answer.

Comment: Btw, you don't even need to use .to_series()

Comment: @MB. - first I was surprised, but find why it working nice and add to answer.